# why css-loader path exists '!'

Tags: webpack, path, css-loader

In webpack bundle file, I don't understand the '!' means what, it seems not separator of path. Can someone tell me?

The simple example such like: "./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/index.css"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRc7v.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
//    supplement expample

/***/ "./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/index.css":
/*!*************************************************************!*\
  !*** ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/index.css ***!
  \*************************************************************/
/***/ (function(module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) {

    enter code here

eval(".....");

/***/ }),
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).